# Connection to MS SQL server with RODBC from mac osx 10.11

Tags: sql-server, r, macos, rodbc, unixodbc

I have downloaded and configured freeTDS and unixODBC as proof I have connected with tsql and isql. When I download `RODBC` from RStudio and try and connect with mssql server I get the following error

```
[RODBC] ERROR: state IM002, code 1606386064, message [iODBC][Driver Manager]
Data source name not found and no default driver specified. Driver could not be loaded
```

From the error I note that iODBC is still being used instead of unixODBC. I then uninstall `RODBC` from RStudio and go to terminal to try and force `RODBC` to install using unixODBC by using

```
export DYLD_LIBRARY_PATH=/usr/local/lib:${DYLD_LIBRARY_PATH}
R CMD INSTALL /Users/<username>/Downloads/RODBC_1.3-13.tar.gz
```

So the computer knows to install in the location of unixODBC.

I get the same error as above. I am not sure if I am doing something wrong or if there is another way to make R use unixODBC?

I am also open to a suggestion on how to make iODBC to work. I am new at this whole connecting to servers business.

Comment: Without seeing the code you used, it's very difficult to know what advice to give you. Are you using a data source name with `odbcConnect` or a connection string with `odbcDriverConnect`? If a DSN, what is the configuration of the DSN?

Comment: I used this to try and connect  `library("RODBC", lib.loc="/usr/local/lib/R/3.3/site-library")``con <- odbcConnect("xxx.xxx.x.xx", uid="<user loggin>", pwd="<user password>")`I named the DSN with ip address of the computer I am trying to connect to, it is a little funky but seemed to work when connecting from the terminal.

Comment: Well there's something I've never tried to do.  If you don't mind my asking, why not configure the DSN on your machine? Connecting to another computer in order to use it DSN seems like adding an unnecessary step.

Comment: I may be confused as I am a new to all of this but this is what I have on my laptop (mac). I installed freetds with homebrew in the freetds.confg file I have                                                                                                   `# A typical Microsoft server
[abc.afg.a.cf]
 host = abc.afg.a.cf
 port = xxxxx
 tds version = 7.4
 client charset = UTF-8`                                                                        I then installed unixODBC with homebrew and configured the odbc.ini and the odbcinst.ini , as follows

Comment: odbc.ini `[abc.afg.a.cf]
Description         = Test to SQLServer
Driver              = FreeTDS
Trace               = Yes
TraceFile           = /tmp/sql.log
Database            = AAAA
Servername          = abc.afg.a.cf
UserName            = <username>
Password            = <password>
Port                = xxxxx
Protocol            = 7.4
ReadOnly            = No
RowVersioning       = No
ShowSystemTables    = No
ShowOidColumn       = No
FakeOidIndex        = No`

Comment: odbcinst.ini `[FreeTDS]
Description = TD Driver (MSSQL)
Driver = /usr/local/lib/libtdsodbc.so
Setup = /usr/local/lib/libtdsodbc.so
UsageCount=1`

Comment: All in hopes to connect to a MS machine using SQLEXPRESS

Answer (score 0):

For OS 10.13.3, I got r RODBC and python pymssql working with MS SQL using the following commands:

```
brew install homebrew/core/freetds091 --with-unixodbc.  
brew link --force freetds@0.91  
pip install pymssql
```

and then making the following edits to /Users//.odbc.ini

```
[SQLServer]   
Description = "my server"  
Driver = /usr/local/lib/libtdsodbc.so  
Trace=No  
Server = "my server"  
Port=1433   
TDS_Version=8.0  
Database= "my db"
```